# How do I set the body content of another view in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC project setup with 2 views. My scenario is as follows:

View1 has a link. Clicking on that link should populate the contents of View2 with certain text. How do I set the body of my View2.cshtml in View1 using jQuery?

I tried something like this but nothing happens.

```
$("#link").click(function () {
  string result = "Blah blah";
  $("/Home/RawData.cshtml").html(result);                                                
});
```

The RawData view is empty:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RawData";
}
<body>    
    <!-- This will be populated dynamically -->
</body>
```

Controller for RawData:

```
public ActionResult RawData()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your need to redirect to that view and pass it the text you want. Show the `RawData()` method and the view it generates.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: RawData is a cshtml file. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: You need to show the controller method for `RawData()` (you cannot navigate directly to a `.cshtml` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: The controller just returns the view

Comment: I have edited the question to show the code for the RawData controller

Comment: Change the method to `public ActionResult RawData(string text)` and the script needs to be `location.href = '@Url.Action("RawData", "Home")' + ?text=' + result;` Then you can pass the text to the view by initializing a model and setting the value of a property, or pass it using a `ViewBag` property. But its unclear what you really trying to do here. How is the value of `result` generated?

Comment: The both of the views are in the page or do you want to get the html from `RawData` view and present it in `view1` or `view2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be done using a iframe. Just by setting the source of the iframe on the click event from view1 and passing the string as querystring as suggested by @stephen_muecke.

I mean:

```
$('#iframe_i').attr('src', "/Home/RawData/?text="+$("#myTextBox").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the RawData Action from ActionResult to PartialViewResult:

```
public PartialViewResult RawData(){
    return PartialView("View2Url");
}
```

Then in the JS you can use ajax and do something like:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    $.get('/Home/RawData', {}, function(data){
        $('body').html(data);
    });
});
```